# Send an array of numbers from Java to Arduino

Tags: java, arduino, arduino-uno

I need to send an amount of numbers given by the user from Java to an Arduino UNO.

The numbers have to be random.

I had this two ideas:

1. Send the numbers one by one

   ```
   for(int count = 0; count< amount; count++){                             
       Arduino.sendData(array[count]);
   }
   ```
2. Write a TXT file with the numbers and read one by one from there.

Questions:

- Is there anyway to just send the array?
- If using the option 1, I need to do an `input = Serial.read();` everytime a new number is sent?
- In option 2, if I can open the txt file and read one by one, can it be done without a SD card? (reading the file from PC)
- Is there another way (not necessarily easier) to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can send it.

1. ```
   Arduino.sendData(array);
   ```
2. ```
   public void sendData(int array[])
   {

   }
   ```

Comment: I will try that. Do you know how to send it back to java? I need to sort the array in the arduino and print it back on java. Thanks :)

Comment: You do not return, You send a pointer and not a copy.
How is your object defined ?